# Reading very small numbers in R

Tags: r, read.table

So I'm trying to generate some plots for my dataset, but I've encountered a certain problem with some values.

Some values are very small: `1.62132528761108e-1916` small to be exact and when it's read on R, it turns into `0.00000000000e+00`

I'm reading my data like so:

```
df <- read.table("path/to/file", header = T, sep = ' ', numerals = "no.loss")
```

and even with the `numerals` flag set to `no.loss`, the number turns to 0.

How can I read the exact number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard numeric data type in R (8-byte double precision) does not support such small numbers. The smallest positive number is about 1e-300

```
.Machine$double.xmin
# [1] 2.225074e-308
```

Can you convince whatever program generates your input data to save it in, say, logarithms?

Comment: Or, depending on if the math downstream supports it, apply a scaling factor.